# How to access children property on Firebase Realtime Database snapshot in flutter?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I used to write snapshot.children.allObjects in swift. How do I write this code in flutter with firebase? If I use snapshot.value as! [String: Any] snapshot's nodes are not retrieved in order from database. Is there any other option to retrieve objects in order from Firebase console?

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
        else { return completion(nil, []) }

    snapshot.forEach({ (postSnapshot) in
        print(postSnapshot)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = new FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);
_messagesRef = database.reference().child('users');
database.reference().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   var names=snapshot.value["name"].toString();
   var email=snapshot.value["email"].toString();
});
```

Assuming you have this database:

```
users
  name: "userx"
  email: "userx@gmail.com"
```

First you configure the database, then reference the location at child `users`. Then you attach a listener `once()` to retrieve the data.

Check the following links:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/event.dart#L27
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-

Comment: The problem is that Firebase snapshot doesn't appear in order. When I want query users based on timestamp for example I can't do that because I use pagination in my app that retrieves segments of users.

Comment: why dont u use a query like orderByChild or startAt or endAt? https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/query.dart

Comment: I do, but the key that I end on is not really the last key because the keys are not retrieved in order from firebase.